# can't choose first generic child variant of the list

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I finally set a 2 level child product cart.

the problem is that i had to create fake child products with property "stock" set to zero (so can't be added to cart) 
and also give them ordering=1 (i gave 2,3,4,... to the other real products)
so that the fake products are shown first in the dropdown list.

this is because i noticed that first elements of dropdown list can't be selected!

example: for generic child variant "color" i created child products called "choose a color","black","white","green",... the "choose a color" is shown first in the list so it doesn't matter if it can't be selected when i reach the page where i have to select the color!

Is that a usual problem workaround or it can be done in a proper way? thanks

Comment: What e-commerce extension are you using? Do you have a link to the site?

Comment: i'm still working local: can't give you url. i'm using virtuemart 2 as you can see in the tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using virtuemart 2 and I'm not sure what version. That is kind of how it works. This might help you though so you don't have to create fake child products.

https://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=110203.msg410620#msg410620